# ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND after upgrade android version

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

My android app was getting application error 
`net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///data/user/0/com.isen.SAMApp/no_backup/www/default/index.html)` after upgrade my samsung S6 android version 5 to version 6.0.1

I also tested in ios and other android devices, it is working with no error prompt. Error only happen after upgrade the android version.

What is this warning and I need advice for better solutions.

Comment: looks like there is a path issue.
it should be like `/com.isen.SAMApp/android_assets/www/default`

Comment: yes. but no idea why the path will change to ...//no_backup/www/default/index.html after the software upgrade.

Comment: check `<content src="index.html" />` in config.xml, is it pointing to right path ?

Comment: this is IBM mobileFirst platform project. I was unable to found the `<content src="index.html" />` inside the config file.

Comment: What is "no_backup"? Is there such a folder in your project?

Comment: @IdanAdar no such folder inside my project. Actually it happen after user upgrade android version and open the app. Everything works again after uninstall and reinstall the app from google play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be an unhandled scenario in MobileFirst.

If you are able to reproduce this also outside of your own application, please open an IBM support ticket (PMR) for the development team to investigate.